# Pandas datetime inconsistent format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-datetime

I hope someone can help me with the following:
I'm trying to convert my data to daily averages using:

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datum WSM-09'])
df_daily_avg = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D', key='timestamp')).mean()
```

df['Datum WSM-09'] looks like this:

```
0          6-3-2020 12:30
1          6-3-2020 12:40
2          6-3-2020 12:50
3          6-3-2020 13:00
4          6-3-2020 13:10
               ...       
106785    18-3-2022 02:00
106786    18-3-2022 02:10
106787    18-3-2022 02:20
106788    18-3-2022 02:30
106789    18-3-2022 02:40
Name: Datum WSM-09, Length: 106790, dtype: object
```

However, when executing the first line the data under "timestamp" is inconsistent. The last rows displayed in the picture are correct. For the first ones, it should be 2020-03-06 12:30. The month and the day are switched around.

Many thanks

[image]

Comment: For debugging it is much better to add some sample data as text/code instead as image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the "dayfirst" option:

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datum WSM-09'], dayfirst=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

In https://xkcd.com/1179 Randall Munroe explains
that "you're doing it Wrong."

[image: iso8601]

Your source column is apparently object / text.
The March 18th timestamps are unambiguous,
as there's fewer than 18 months in the year.
The ambiguous March 6th timestamps make the hair
on the back of the black cat stand on end.

You neglected to specify a timestamp format,
given that the source column is ambiguously formatted.

Please [RTFM](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

> format : str, default None
>
> The strftime to parse time, e.g. "%d/%m/%Y". Note that "%f" will parse all the way up to nanoseconds. See [strftime documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for more information on choices.

You tried offering a value of `None`,
which is not a good match to your business needs.
I don't know what all of your input data looks like,
but perhaps `%d-%m-%Y %H:%M` would better
match your needs.